# Symfony: RuntimeException on SierraOS - Unable to create the cache directory

Tags: apache, symfony, macos-sierra

Creating a new symfony project has been a breeze until I upgraded to SierraOS.  I have this error after creating a new project from CLI and using symfony:

> [RuntimeException]                                 Unable to create
>   the cache directory (/cache/)

I have followed the permission guides [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html) but this didn't help

I have also followed the guides from [here](http://www.bryanlor.com/blog/symfony2-troubleshooting-runtimeexception-unable-create-cache-directory), but this didn't help.  If ever you have encountered such error and have found a fix, please help as I have found myself completely stuck and I needed to move on with my projects.

**OS: Sierra using Symfony: 2.8**

Comment: Which server do you run - `nginx` or `Apache`? I've seem some instances where the first command used for determining the user has actually returned invalid user...

Comment: I am using Apache.  It's one of those updates that I've been dreading to do. Now am just unable to move on with my projects